# Gemspecs and bundler in rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, bundler

I have a RAILS plugin for coffeescript testing

https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice

with a gemspec defined as

```
# Provide a simple gemspec so you can easily use your
# project in your rails apps through git.
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "jasminerice"
  s.summary     = "Pain free coffeescript unit testing for Rails 3.1 using jasmine"
  s.description = "Full support for the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline when bdd'ing your coffeescript or javascript using jasmine"
  s.files       = `git ls-files`.split "\n"
  s.authors     = ["Brad Phelan"]
  s.version     = "0.0.6"
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.add_dependency( 'haml' )
end
```

At the bottom I have added the haml dependency. If jasminerice is included in the client Gemfile as

```
gem 'jasminerice'
```

then it fails because 'haml' is not included. If haml is included explicity as

```
gem 'jasminerice'
gem 'haml'
```

then all is ok. This doesn't mesh with my understanding of Gemfiles and gemspecs. Is there something obvious I have missed.

Comment: What's the output when you run `gem dependency jasminerice`?

Comment: @Thiago: `Gem jasminerice-0.0.6
  haml (>= 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a `gemspec` line in your gems Gemfile.

From http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/ :

> When developing a gem, use the `gemspec` method in your Gemfile to avoid duplication. In general, a gem’s Gemfile should contain the Rubygems source and a single gemspec line.